# Grammar relating to 인가 in 것인가: 설계할 것인가 하는 것

Tags: grammar

부귀환을 인가할 때 가장 먼저 고려해야 할 사항은 루프이득을 얼마로 설계할 것인가 하는 것이다.

Could anyone explain the grammar 인가 in 것인가 here? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is the question ending ㄴ/는/은가.

이다 acts as adjective in Korean, so we add ㄴ가 to denote question, and it becomes 인가.

Analyzing your sentence,

루프이득을 얼마로 설계할 것인가 => What value will the loop gain be designed

루프이득을 얼마로 설계할 것인가 하는 것 => Referring to the question itself

부귀환을 인가할 때 가장 먼저 고려해야 할 사항은 루프이득을 얼마로 설계할 것인가 하는 것이다.

=> When negative feedback is applied, the very first thing to consider will be "in what value will the loop gain be designed".

The translation may not be correct as I don't know the exact term in Finance and Electronics.

Comment: Thanks. Actually 인가하다 means "to apply" here. However, I couldn't find the meaning in dictionary though. Aslo where the word "value" come from in the sentence?

Comment: 얼마 here means "how much", i.e., "what value".